# Font location for django-cairo-text

Tags: python, django, text

Where do you put custom fonts for django-cairo-text?

https://github.com/akaihola/django-cairo-text

Answer (score 0):

Wherever the font engine for your OS expects them to be. If you want to use a custom font file then you'll need to [load it manually](http://cairographics.org/freetypepython/) then inject it into the `CAIROTEXT_PRESETS` setting.